# While typing in a text field enable a keystroke ENTER to activate a button in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, keyboard-events, scenebuilder

Such as typing into the Google search box the hitting ENTER activates the search

I've just been introduced to JavaFX and Scene Builder a few days ago so I'm learning the basics here. I have the latest version of JavaFX and am using Scene Builder to facilitate action events. Also, any pointers to relevant tutorials would be helpful. At one point in the day I was focused on the Keyboard section of the coding panel of Scene Builder, especially with the "On Key Released" event with no results. Thanks in advance

Here's a rough idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
@FXML
Text Field theTextField;

@FXML
Button theButton;

@FXML  
void ButtonPressed() {
    //do stuff here
}

@FXML
//when ENTER is pressed the button is activated
void textFieldEnterPressed() {
    ButtonPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `FXML` file, add a `onKeyPressed` handler

```
 <TextField fx:id="yourTextField" onKeyPressed="#handleEnterPressed">
```

Implement the handler in you `Controller`

```
@FXML
public void handleEnterPressed(KeyEvent event)
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        // do some actions 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In TextField, when you press Enter, you get notification through `onAction`. In your Java code you can add:

```
@FXML
private void handleTFAction(ActionEvent event) {
    TextField source = (TextField)event.getSource();
    System.out.println("You entered: "+source.getText());
}
```

In your FXML (or through JavaFX SceneBuilder designer) hook it up to your TextField's OnAction event. In FXML it looks something like this:

```
<TextField onAction="#handleTFAction" ... />
```